# How can I view all the gems for a specific gem group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile

I'd like to see all the gems that are loaded for the `test` environment, with versions and dependencies. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could roll your own:

```
require 'bundler/setup'

group = :development

deps = Bundler.load.dependencies.select do |dep|
  dep.groups.include?(group) or dep.groups.include?(:default)
end

puts "Gems included by the bundle in group #{group}:"
deps.each do |dep|
  spec = dep.to_spec
  puts "* #{spec.name} (#{spec.version})"
end
```

Example `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thor'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'pry'
end
```

Example output:

```
Gems included by the bundle in group development:
* sinatra (1.4.1)
* thor (0.17.0)
* rspec (2.13.0)
* pry (0.9.12)
```

Comment: Awesome! I've made a rake task out of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It should already the there in your Gemfile

Anything in a block that specifies test will be part of your test environment, anything outside of the test block but not in another block would also be loaded.

All of the dependencies should be listed in the Gemfile.lock

EDIT

OK, based on your feedback, this should do what you want.

```
Rails c test
```

to open a console in the test environment

```
pp Gem.loaded_specs.sort
```

This will prettyprint all of the specs in alphabetical order

Comment: They are, but I thought that maybe there is some command, similar to `bundle show`, that would show me the gems for a specific environment.

Comment: Updated as per your comment